# How to Sumproduct in Excel if partial string is found ignoring characters and specific cell values

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sumproduct

I have a table similar to the one below in Excel and I want to calculate the sum of all the columns where "*weightl*" shows up in the variable name (first row).

However, if the value is 8888 or a character/string this should be ignored.

[image]

In this case, the result should be 64.

I tried using something like `{+sumproduct(sumif(A1:F1,"\*weightl\*",A2:F4))}`

However, this only returns 16 (the result of the first row). Also, I don't know how to exclude 8888 values.

Would be great if you could support with a formula to solve this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to SO. For this you'll need an array formula:

`=SUM(IF(IFERROR(SEARCH("weight",$A$1:$F$1),0)>0,IF($A$2:$F$4<>8888,$A$2:$F$4)))`

> **NOTE:** Because this in an array formula, it must be inserted with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd> instead of only
>   <kbd>ENTER</kbd> or it won't work!

[image]

How this works?

1. `IF($A$2:$F$4<>8888,$A$2:$F$4)` will return an array of only those cells which value are not equal to 8888
2. `IF(IFERROR(SEARCH("weight",$A$1:$F$1),0)>0,IF($A$2:$F$4<>8888,$A$2:$F$4))` will check previous array of values, and it will search the word *weight* in row 1. If found, those values will be checked as *ok*. If not, those values will be ignored in the final sum.

As you can see in the image I posted, final result is 64.

Hope you can adapt this to your needs.

Comment: Just beaten me to an answer, but I would use `=SUMPRODUCT(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("weightl",A1:F1))*(ISNUMBER(A2:F4)*(A2:F4<>8,888)),A2:F4)` instead. No array entered formula and no `IFERROR` :)

Comment: @JvdV I'm not good at all at handling SUMPRODUCT. I know I should, but I'm not :) . For me, is easier to use other formulas or array formulas, because I can understand what's happening and the logic, but SUMPRODUCT is like *magic* for me. But your answer is good and it works! Please, post it!

Comment: Feel free to use the suggestion in your answer, I'm not bothered. Keep it packed in one solution :). Walk through evaluation carefully to check how it works. Mind you, `SUMPRODUCT` still is an array function!